# Find average ID then fetch data with same ID from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to find the average grid_id in the client table then fetch x and y from the grid table with the corresponding id. I have tried this query here:

```
SELECT round(AVG(client_id)) as testyy, grid.x,grid.y 
FROM client
JOIN grid
ON client.grid_id = grid.grid_id
WHERE grid.grid_id = AVG(client_id)
group by GRID.X,GRID.Y
```

but cant seem to get it to work.

DESIRED OUTPUT: average grid location

EXAMPLE DATA: grid table

```
INSERT INTO grid (x,y) values (-10,-10);
INSERT INTO grid (x,y) values (-10,-9);
INSERT INTO grid (x,y) values (-10,-8);
INSERT INTO grid (x,y) values (-10,-7);
INSERT INTO grid (x,y) values (-10,-6);
INSERT INTO grid (x,y) values (-10,-5);
INSERT INTO grid (x,y) values (-10,-4);
```

EXAMPLE DATA: CLIENT TABLE

```
INSERT INTO client (name,payment_method,grid_id,service_id) VALUES ('Derri','cash',563,57);
INSERT INTO client (name,payment_method,grid_id,service_id) VALUES ('Eil','card',616,758);
INSERT INTO client (name,payment_method,grid_id,service_id) VALUES ('Sid','cash',595,59);
INSERT INTO client (name,payment_method,grid_id,service_id) VALUES ('Amelia','card',601,60);
INSERT INTO client (name,payment_method,grid_id,service_id) VALUES ('Lewis','card',479,61);
INSERT INTO client (name,payment_method,grid_id,service_id) VALUES ('Mel','card',480,62);
INSERT INTO client (name,payment_method,grid_id,service_id) VALUES ('Gordon','card',480,63);
INSERT INTO client (name,payment_method,grid_id,service_id) VALUES ('Gino','card',479,64);
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: added the example data and desired result

Comment: Taking an average of id's doesn't make much sense. For example, the average of a few integers may (generally) not even be an integer; so how is your average id going to match any id at all? Something must be wrong in this question.

Comment: grid_id is missing in grid table.

Comment: there multiple entries for a grid id which relates to the grid table. If I do a query round(avg(grid_id) from the client table it results in 609. then if i go to the grid table and find grid 609 x is -6 and y is -2, I need to select this result from the query. Hope it makes sense

Comment: Regarding the grid_id it is auto incremented in the grid table using a sequence and trigger.

Answer (score 0):

> Find average ID then fetch data with same ID from another table

Maybe a subquery will do the trick.  Try:

```
select x, y
from grid
where id = ( 
  select round( avg( grid_id ) )
  from client 
) ;
```